# Pass string into SQL WHERE IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-in

I am working on a query page where a user selects a value which represents different types, each identified by an ID.
The problem is selecting these IDs from the data base using the WHERE IN method.

This is my SQL statement

```
SELECT M.REG_NO, T.TYPE_ID 
    FROM MAIN AS M 
        INNER JOIN CLASSIFICATION AS C 
            ON M.REG_NO = C.REG_NO
        INNER JOIN TYPE AS T 
            ON T.TYPE_ID = C.TYPE_ID
    WHERE T.TYPE_ID IN (@Types)
```

it will work for one single value, eg. 46, but NOT if the value is in brackets, eg. (46) or ('46'), the way it should be for the IN.

I am using visual studio which is auto generating the method to access the table adapter to get the values so I think I HAVE to do this through SQL.

I am passing a string, eg. Types = "46,267,2010" , into the adapter method which passes the string into the @Types in the SQL statement.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Don't know SQL Server, but in Oracle, you can't pass in a bound variable like your @Types - you have to pass in a separate var or constant for each IN value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem -- not sure why TSQL hasn't dealt with it yet.  Anyway, the solution I've found works best for me is to convert the variable to a table, and then you can use IN() on it just fine.

Starting with the function:

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[ParseStringList]  (@StringArray nvarchar(max) )  
Returns @tbl_string Table  (ParsedString nvarchar(max))  As  

BEGIN 

DECLARE @end Int,
        @start Int

SET @stringArray =  @StringArray + ',' 
SET @start=1
SET @end=1

WHILE @end<Len(@StringArray)
    BEGIN
        SET @end = CharIndex(',', @StringArray, @end)
        INSERT INTO @tbl_string 
            SELECT
                Substring(@StringArray, @start, @end-@start)

        SET @start=@end+1
        SET @end = @end+1
    END

RETURN
END
```

And then to use the function...

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE SomeFieldValue In (Select ParsedString From dbo.ParseStringList(@Types))
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because you need to have a set of values separated by commas. Like

```
WHERE
T.TYPE_ID IN ('46', '45', '44');
```

Are you usign SQL Server or Oracle, MySQL?

If you have a string composed of your multiple values such as

```
T.TYPE_ID IN ('46,45,44');
```

You might need a function that will explode your string usign a delimiter (split or whatever it is called depending on you DBMS)

Comment: Its SQL Server. I tried entering the values like ('46', '45', '44') and it didnt work.

Comment: What's your data type?  '45' assumes Type_ID is char/varchar/nvarchar data.  If Type_ID is integer, you would use (46,45,44) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The following `Select` working fine for me:

```
 SELECT M.REG_NO, T.TYPE_ID 
        FROM MAIN AS M 
            INNER JOIN CLASSIFICATION AS C 
                ON M.REG_NO = C.REG_NO
            INNER JOIN TYPE AS T 
                ON T.TYPE_ID = C.TYPE_ID
        WHERE (','+@Types+',') LIKE '%,' +T.TYPE_ID+ ',%'
```